# Test if a string contains only whitespace and non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: bash

I tried the following solution.

```
if !(($str =~ ^.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*$)); then
  continue;
fi
```

It seems there's something wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your regex and syntax is incorrect. You need not use regex at all, just need glob for this:

```
checkStr() {
   [[ $1 != *[a-zA-Z0-9]* ]]
}
```

This will return `false` if even one alphanumeric is found in the input. Otherwise `true` is returned.

**Test it:**

```
$> if checkStr 'abc'; then
   echo "true case"
else
   echo "false case"
fi    
false case

$> if checkStr '=:() '; then
   echo "true case"
else
   echo "false case"
fi
true case

$> if checkStr '=:(x) '; then
   echo "true case"
else
   echo "false case"
fi
false case
```

Comment: I need the expression that returns True if a string matches a mix of zero or more whitespace and zero or more non-alphanumeric characters. If there is at least one alpha-numeric character it should return False. That's because I find the opposite and then negate the result with !

Comment: @xralf The `!=` operator here does that, unless you have a specific set of nonalphanumeric characters in mind.

Comment: @anubhava The examples you provided are exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`[:alnum:]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class) character class. I'm negating using the `^`:

```
if [[ "${str}" =~ ^[^[:alnum:]]$ ]] ; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```